# alternative to json_decode before PHP 5.2

Tags: php, json, php-5.2

Is there a simple alternative to using json_decode function in php versions prior to 5.2? I am feeling lazy at this time of night and can't be bothered to update php yet.
Cheers.

Comment: Updating PHP is probably the distinctly less lazy solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find six alternatives at [json.org](http://json.org/)

Answer (score 4):

The comments for `json_decode()` include a few possible solutions.

[Here's one that decodes by itself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#91216) (**though you shouldn't use it since it uses `eval()`! Oops.**), and [here's one that uses a PEAR module](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#80606).

Comment: The self-decoding version is just not safe. It uses `eval()` and does not sanitise/check the input. Try using `json_decode('{}; global $isAdmin; $isAdmin=TRUE');` to change global variables.

Comment: @Shi: eek, I guess I didn't read it in enough detail back then >_< I've learned over the past two years, I promise!

Comment: There is a regex method of checking JSON input whether it's safe to pass to `eval`, though.

Answer (score 3):

http://mike.teczno.com/JSON/JSON.phps